# Simple way to split a sequence of null-separated strings in C++

Tags: c++, stl, std

I have a series of strings stored in a single array, separated by nulls (for example ['f', 'o', 'o', '\0', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'...]), and I need to split this into a `std::vector<std::string>` or similar.

I could just write a 10-line loop to do this using `std::find` or `strlen` (in fact I just did), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler/more elegant way to do it, for example some STL algorithm I've overlooked, which can be coaxed into doing this.

It is a fairly simple task, and it wouldn't surprise me if there's some clever STL trickery that can be applied to make it even simpler.

Any takers?

Comment: some of the answers found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) can be applied to your problem, be sure to have a look.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate since these strings are null-terminated, and all c-string algorithms apply (calling constructors on raw pointers in the buffer, using `strlen`, etc.)

Comment: Problem: how do you know when to stop? Or do you know the length of the array / have a sentinel (e.g. two consecutive zero chars)?

Comment: @Konrad: I know where the last string ends. You can assume that it is the end of the buffer, or two consecutive nulls. Both can be arranged trivially. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My two cents :

```
const char* p = str;
std::vector<std::string> vector;

do {
  vector.push_back(std::string(p));
  p += vector.back().size() + 1;
} while ( // whatever condition applies );
```

Comment: That's really nice! Just the choice of `vector` as a variable name is, IMO, not so clever.

Comment: Since the list is double-NUL terminated, it can't contain empty strings (since that would look like the end of the list: ii.e. `"abc\0\0def\0ghi\0"`). So, you can just put the `while` at the top, to correctly deal with an empty list: `while (*p) { ... }`

Answer (score 9):

Boost solution:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
//input_array must be a Range containing the input.
boost::split(
    strs,
    input_array,
    boost::is_any_of(boost::as_array("\0")));
```

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but relies on Boost. For something as simple as this, I'd prefer a standard-library-only solution

Comment: In cases where a pistol would be enough, a bazooka would likely get you both killed.

Comment: @Xaade - A lot of projects are using boost already, so it is not a big deal. A solution with similar code complexity that just uses Standard C++ components would obviously be better. (As a side note, this was actually quite difficult to get right, due the requirement for boost::as_array.)

Comment: @Xaade: If a Leopard 2 tank is approaching you with an open hatch, a pistol would be enough, too. But it would require a lot of skill to do it right, the bazooka is more safe.

Comment: @phresnel Obviously a pistol isn't enough if the user isn't skilled. However, this is code, and if the code works every time, then no need for something bigger.

Comment: @Xaade: Though this argument also holds for the boost solution.

Answer (score 6):

The following relies on `std::string` having an implicit constructor taking a `const char*`, making the loop a very simple two-liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template< std::size_t N >
std::vector<std::string> split_buffer(const char (&buf)[N])
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    for(const char* p=buf; p!=buf+sizeof(buf); p+=result.back().size()+1)
        result.push_back(p);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test = split_buffer("wrgl\0brgl\0frgl\0srgl\0zrgl");

    for (auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << '"' << *it << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This solution assumes the buffer's size is known and the criterion for the end of the list of strings. If the list is terminated by `"\0\0"` instead, the condition in the loop needs to be changed from `p!=foo+sizeof(foo)` to `*p`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I came up with myself, assuming the buffer ends immediately after the last string:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::vector<char>& buf) {
    auto cur = buf.begin();
    while (cur != buf.end()) {
        auto next = std::find(cur, buf.end(), '\0');
        drives.push_back(std::string(cur, next));
        cur = next + 1;
    }
    return drives;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant and actual solution (compared to my other answer) uses getline and boils down to 2 lines with only C++2003, and no manual loop bookkeeping and conditioning is required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const char foo[] = "meh\0heh\0foo\0bar\0frob";

    std::istringstream ss (std::string(foo, foo + sizeof foo));
    std::string str;

    while (getline (ss, str, '\0'))
        std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

However, note how the range based string constructor already indicates an inherent problem with splitting-at-'\0's: You must know the exact size, or find some other char-combo for the Ultimate Terminator.

Comment: Yep, fortunately I do know the exact size. The data comes from a Microsoft API, so I'm stuck with the null-separated format. :)

Comment: I don't like the fact that this initializes and reads from a stream, but I like the simplicity of the loop. I wish we'd find a loop as simple as that that operates directly on the data, rather than copying into a stream.

Comment: True :) On the other hand, you could see the stream as a (slightly overblown) holder of the state we had to maintain manually.

Answer (score 1):

A bad answer, actually, but I doubted your claim of a 10 line loop for manual splitting. 4 Lines do it for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using std::vector;

    const char foo[] = "meh\0heh\0foo\0bar\0frob";

    vector<vector<char> > strings(1);
    for (const char *it=foo, *end=foo+sizeof(foo); it!=end; ++it) {
        strings.back().push_back(*it);
        if (*it == '\0') strings.push_back(vector<char>());
    }

    std::cout << "number of strings: " << strings.size() << '\n';
    for (vector<vector<char> >::iterator it=strings.begin(), end=strings.end(); 
         it!=end; ++it)
        std::cout << it->data() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -9):

In C, string.h has this guy:

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

the example on cplusplus.com :

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It's not C++, but it will work

Comment: `strtok` is really, really bad. Don't ever use it.

Comment: It will not work because the strings are NULL-separated. strtok only works on string without null-separation.

Comment: How can you tell `strtok` to split at `\0`'s ?