# Retrieving VolumeDetails of WINDOWS Drives - stuck with 'char []' to 'LPCWSTR' conversion

Tags: windows, winapi, wchar-t, lpcwstr

I am trying to get the `VolumeDetails` of my WINDOWS system- Drive label plus its respective Volume Serial number. I've tried since an hour and built a code which gone wrong in syntax. At present I am getting the following error with it- 
`error C2664: 'GetVolumeInformationW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char []' to 'LPCWSTR'`
Here is my code:

```
    // getVolDrive.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
//wchar_t mydrives[5];// = " A: ";
char mydrives[] = " A: ";

string retVolSno(char drives[]) //wchar_t drives[]
{
    DWORD dwSerial;
    stringstream ss;
    cout<<drives<<endl;
    if(!GetVolumeInformation(drives, NULL, 0, &dwSerial, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        ss<<"Error: "<<GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        ss<<hex<<dwSerial;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string cVolSno;
    ULONG DriveMask = _getdrives(); 
    if(DriveMask == 0)
        printf("_getdrives() failed with failure code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    else
    {
        printf("This machine has the following logical drives:\n");
        while (DriveMask)
            { 
                cout << "In While" << endl;
                if(DriveMask & 1)
                printf("%s", mydrives);
                wcout << mydrives << endl;
                cVolSno = retVolSno(mydrives);
                cout<<cVolSno<<endl;
                ++mydrives[1];
                DriveMask >>= 1;
            }
    }
    //std::transform(cVolSno.begin(), cVolSno.end(),cVolSno.begin(), ::toupper);
    //cout<<cVolSno<<endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried replacing `char` with `wchar_t`, I didn't got any build errors, but while executing the application, got `Error Code 3- Path not found!`.

**CODE MODIFIED:**

```
    // getVolDrive.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
//wchar_t mydrives[5];// = " A: ";
char mydrives[] = " A:\\\\ ";

string retVolSno(char drives[]) //wchar_t drives[]
{
    DWORD dwSerial;
    stringstream ss;
    wchar_t text[10];
    mbstowcs(text,drives,100); //strlen(drives)+1
    LPWSTR ptr = text;

    if(!GetVolumeInformation(ptr, NULL, 0, &dwSerial, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        ss<<"Error: "<<GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        ss<<hex<<dwSerial;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string cVolSno;
    ULONG DriveMask = _getdrives(); 
    if(DriveMask == 0)
        printf("_getdrives() failed with failure code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    else
    {
        printf("This machine has the following logical drives:\n");
        while (DriveMask)
            {
                if(DriveMask & 1)
                printf("%s \n", mydrives);
                cVolSno = retVolSno(mydrives);
                std::transform(cVolSno.begin(), cVolSno.end(),cVolSno.begin(), ::toupper);
                cout<<cVolSno<<endl;
                ++mydrives[1];
                DriveMask >>= 1;
            }
    }
    //std::transform(cVolSno.begin(), cVolSno.end(),cVolSno.begin(), ::toupper);
    //cout<<cVolSno<<endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
This machine has the following logical drives:
ERROR: 123
ERROR: 123
 C:\\
ERROR: 123
 D:\\
ERROR: 123
 E:\\
ERROR: 123
```

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see **at least** these main issues:

1) `wchar_t` is the right type because you're compiling for UNICODE, you can write *generic* code using `TCHAR` macro or explicitly declare your buffer as `wchar_t` but that's what to do.

2) You have that error because you're passing wrong path to `GetVolumeInformation()` (trailing backslash is required so `A:` must become `A:\`).

Moreover please note that you have a little bit more easy way to achieve same result, you can use `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` to directly get a `NULL` delimited string list. Split it using, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243723/simple-way-to-split-a-sequence-of-null-separated-strings-in-c) (don't forget UNICODE) and use `c_str()` with each entry.

**EDIT** about your modified code:
Why you drive path is `A:\\` (escaped to `A:\\\\`)? Just **one** trailing backslash is needed so `mydrives` has to be declared as:

```
wchar_t mydrives[] = L"A:\\";
```

**EDIT 2**: there are more errors in your code so I'll post a reviewed version. There are more things I'd change but I'll point out just what doesn't actually work.

1. Function `retVolSno` to read volume serial number. Original version were almost right, in your modified version you perform useless character conversion. What you had to do was just to accept a `wchar_t` drive path.
2. Global variable `mydrives`. You actually don't need any global variable for that. It must be `wchar_t` and space before/after path are useless. One trailing backslash is needed. Line where you increment character value (`++mydrives[0];`) must be changed accordingly (index 0 instead of 1).
3. Check for drive availability. After `if(DriveMask & 1)` you did forget `{` then you won't print drive name but you'll perform `GetVolumeInformation()` even on unavailable drives (error 123). That's why indentation is important...
4. You're mixing UNICODE/NOT UNICODE and C/C++ stuff. I strongly suggest you pick one of them and you keep it (C or C++? UNICODE or NOT UNICODE?). For example you used C function `printf()` to print stuff and you have both `std::string` and `wchar_t` things.

Let's put everything together to have a *working version*. First the function to read serial number given drive path:

```
wstring getVolumeSerialNumber(const wchar_t* drivePath)
{
    DWORD dwSerial;
    wstringstream ss;

    if (!GetVolumeInformation(drivePath, NULL, 0, &dwSerial, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0))
        ss << L"Error: " << GetLastError();
    else
        ss << hex << dwSerial;

    return ss.str();
}
```

It's almost the same as your original version, just changed to work with UNICODE characters. Then main function that cycles through available drives and print out their serial number:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t drive[] = L"A:\\";

    ULONG driveMask = _getdrives(); 
    if (driveMask == 0)
        wcout << L"_getdrives() failed with failure code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    else
    {
        wcout << L"This machine has the following logical drives:" << endl;
        while (driveMask)
        {
            if (driveMask & 1) 
            {
                wcout << drive << endl;
                wcout << getVolumeSerialNumber(drive) << endl;
            }

            ++drive[0];
            driveMask >>= 1;
        }
    }

    wcin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I declare it `char mydrives[] = " A:\\";`, in the console I am getting only `C:\` which I guess is the wrong path as Error 123 is being returned. I am not getting how to convert this char to L type!

Comment: Do you have A: drive? You **must** use wchar_t (because you're compiling for UNICODE, unless you explicitly call GetVolumeInformationA) for them **and** set string to A:\\ (because one trailing backslash is required).

Comment: Can you please try my code and explain me where I am doing wrong, I've tried declaring `wchar_t` but still same Error codes are returned

Comment: @highlander141 there are few things you have to change, I edited my answer to provide a working example.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , the first parameters should be with trailing slash if drive letter is passed.

```
lpRootPathName [in, optional]
A pointer to a string that contains the root directory of the volume to be described.
If this parameter is NULL, the root of the current directory is used. 
A trailing backslash is required. 
For example, you specify \\MyServer\MyShare as \\MyServer\MyShare\, or the C drive as C:\
```